# How do I know what devices are compatible for Android Studio?

Tags: android, tablet

I am thinking about getting into making Android apps. I have been doing Apple App dev., but don’t have previous experience with Android app dev. I have an iphone, so I was thinking about getting a tablet with Android OS to use with Android Studio. I'm new so forgive me if this sounds weird, but how do I know if a tablet is compatible Android Studio? I haven't bought one yet, does it matter what kind of tablet it is? Is it okay as long as it's got the Android OS? Thanks!

I would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: You don't need to buy anything in the beginning since you can use the emulator. Besides that any smartphone or tablet that you can buy in stores should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! That was very helpful! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

All device is suitable with Android Studio ( if it has Developer Options allow install via USB ) , But I think you should buy China's Brand Device because of weird behavior can make you train with all case in coding, others brand is okay

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give advice! Very helpful! I appreciate it!